# Framework that handles AJAX javascript calls?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have the following scenario:

At the moment, I have a program in C# that makes AJAX calls to a SharePoint server.  The calls are handled manually, meaning I have to do all the plumbing work myself, e.g. maintaining the caller variable in code and in Javascript.  It feels like there is an extra layer in my app, but unlike other layers I feel this one should be handled by something else.

I am already using the Prototype/AJAX framework provided by ASP.Net.  I was wondering are there frameworks out there that can handle the error-prone and troublesome plumbing work for me?

Thanks.

Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), Chris. There's a [whole section of the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) about AJAX. So you can wire up your page to GET an aspx page that Response.Writes some XML, and as long as you set the content type of the Response to be "text/xml" (v. important), the jQuery callback method can very easily read the values from that XML. The wire-up and plumbing is extremely easy to work out. Just follow the examples on that AJAX docs page.